# How to add or remove the specific HTML exist in selected li tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am looking for the solution for my problem - How to add or remove the specific HTML exist in selected li tag

**My HTML code is:**

```
<ul id="property-select-list">
<li class="js-property-select" data-id="1" data-has_media_alt="YES">
    prperty1
</li>
<li class="js-property-select selected" data-id="2" data-has_media_alt="NO">
    prperty2
    <div class="tag-indicator"></div>
</li>
<li class="js-property-select" data-id="3" data-has_media_alt="NO">
    prperty3
    <div class="tag-indicator"></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

**How to add or remove the specific HTML exist in selected li tag.** In my case the specific HTML is `<div class="tag-indicator"></div>`

Please help me to get the solution.

Comment: **Title** unclear, can you make it clearer?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: What you mean by "**selected li tag**"?

Comment: @palaѕн `<li class="js-property-select selected" ...`

Comment: @VBMali do you want to remove `html` inside `<div class="tag-indicator"></div>`? or?

Comment: @abbas: I want to add/remove that complete div element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// Find correct element
const el = document.querySelector(".js-property-select.selected");

// Create new tag-indicator
const newElement = document.createElement('div');
newElement.className = "tag-indicator";

// Append to active element
el.appendChild(newElement);

// Optional; remove it
const toRemove = el.querySelector(".tag-indicator");
el.removeChild(toRemove);
```

```css
.tag-indicator {
height: 10px;
border: 1px dotted orange;
}
```

```html
<ul id="property-select-list">
<li class="js-property-select" data-id="1" data-has_media_alt="YES">
    prperty1
</li>
<li class="js-property-select selected" data-id="2" data-has_media_alt="NO">
    prperty2
    <div class="tag-indicator"></div>
</li>
<li class="js-property-select" data-id="3" data-has_media_alt="NO">
    prperty3
    <div class="tag-indicator"></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

<sub>Note: I've added some css to the `.tag-indicator` to make them visible.</sub>

---

**JQuery**

```js
// Add
$('.js-property-select.selected').append('<div class="tag-indicator"></div>');  

// Optional; Remove
$('.js-property-select.selected > .tag-indicator').remove();
```

```css
.tag-indicator {
height: 10px;
border: 1px dotted orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="property-select-list">
<li class="js-property-select" data-id="1" data-has_media_alt="YES">
    prperty1
</li>
<li class="js-property-select selected" data-id="2" data-has_media_alt="NO">
    prperty2
    <div class="tag-indicator"></div>
</li>
<li class="js-property-select" data-id="3" data-has_media_alt="NO">
    prperty3
    <div class="tag-indicator"></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This resolves adding element, how to remove the element?

Comment: @VBMali Please see last JS lines,, you can remove them by searching for the `tag-indicator` classname to get the DOM element, and then tell the parent to remove it!

Comment: Thank you, I will try to apply this solution. Will accept the answer once I found it working. Thank you so much.

Comment: @VBMali You're welkom! This solution is pure javascript. Would you rather have the same 'steps' only in JQuery? Don't think it will any difference in behaviour.

Comment: I am fine with any, javascript or jquery. I have used your code in our JQuery code, it worked. Still, I would love to have the JQuery code separately if you can provide it. Thanks!

Comment: @VBMali I've added a second code snippet with a pure JQuery solution.

Comment: Thanks. Accepting the answer as the javascript code worked for me. Will try JQuery code too.

Answer (score 2):

**Add the specific HTML**

```
// Add the html only if it does not exists already
if (!$('.js-property-select.selected > .tag-indicator').length) {
    $('.js-property-select.selected').append('<div class="tag-indicator"></div>');
}
```

**Remove the specific HTML**

```
$('.js-property-select.selected > .tag-indicator').remove();
```

Comment: Plus one,  for checking the length. Thanks